# Cant install or download anything

Tags: windows, windows-7

I just bought a new computer and it has Ubuntu already on it, and I want to get rid of it and install windows 7. SO I put my disk in, and I click "Auto Run," And it says the archive manager has had an error. MY computer also came with driver update and installation CD's, same thing happens. The archive manager fails. I also cant download anything from the internet. The archive manager wont let me open anything. How do I get rid of Ubuntu when I cant even run or download anything????

Comment: You need to boot from the Windows 7 disk, not run it on Ubuntu.

Answer (score 0):

you have to boot the windows dvd and after that it's really out of the hands and expertise of ubuntu people. sorry to see you go and I hope you return for a future version! (kubuntu 14.10 is supposed to be spectacular!)